# Can't connect react native to localhost

Tags: ios, react-native

In my iOS app, which includes the React library and its dependencies, I have the following code on startup:

`NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios"];
RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                    moduleName:@"App"
                                             initialProperties:@{}
                                                 launchOptions:@{}];
rootView.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:rootView];`

When I run this in the simulator, even after disabling ATS and running `npm start`, I get:

`Failed to load bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios) with error:(Could not connect to development server.
Ensure the following:
- Node server is running and available on the same network - run 'npm start' from react-native root
- Node server URL is correctly set in AppDelegate
- WiFi is enabled and connected to the same network as the Node Server`

My `package.json` file is this:

`{
    "name": "AwesomeProject",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "react-native-scripts": "1.11.1",
        "jest-expo": "25.0.0",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"
    },
    "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-native-scripts start",
        "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
        "android": "react-native-scripts android",
        "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
        "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "jest-expo"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "expo": "^25.0.0",
        "react": "16.2.0",
        "react-native": "0.52.0",
        "react-navigation": "^1.5.11"
    }
}`

Another thing... it seems that `npm start` causes port 19000, not 8081, to open, but when I go to http://localhost:19000 and use the bundle URL that they provide in that JSON, it tells me that I need to use Expo. But none of that is mentioned in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html, and I'm not sure where to go from here. Any ideas?

Comment: could you post your `package.json`?

Comment: @Stackia posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bring react-native to your existing native iOS project, then `expo` package isn't expected here, and the start script should be `node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start`.

Just follow [Integration with Existing Apps](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html) guide, you only need `react-native` and `react` package. (and `react-navigation` if your app use that for navigation).

Answer (score 0):

Comment this line in AppDelegate.m

```
 jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
```

Use this line:-

```
jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

After that run this to make jsbundle:-

```
 react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
```

Run after this command in xcode . Hope it will make bundle and there is no such error after that ... 
Thanx

Comment: Where can I get this `react-native` executable?

Comment: Ah, I've found it now

Comment: Solved it or not??