# Error when build app on xcode (Failed to load bundle)

Tags: ios, macos, react-native

I'm facing this error after tried to build a new project from xCode and Command Line. Last month stuff was working fine on mac, same wifi connection, same device, same programmer (hehe) same everything. And now this... also, it's important to say that my boss created a new user on mac to start work on his projects of React (not Native, just React) and I think he probably  installed some stuff there and maybe this is the cause of this error, idk...

[image]

also I got this on my node commandLine, it has correlation with the error above?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788013/cant-connect-react-native-to-localhost

Comment: did you check if the path or file "/usr/local/var/run/watchman/saulodonascimento-state" exists? And if the correct access rights are set for the currently logged in user? Change the access rights or maybe try running as root. Also, the path /usr/local/var/run looks a bit weird. Shouldn't it better be /var/run ?

Comment: I found the solution, the problem was permission that my user didn't had to access "saulodonascimento-state". Now I'm facing new permission problems but it's fine, just need to unlock the folders.